# Error al compilar libreria escpos en python

Tags: python, epson

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al compilar con pyinstaller --onefile codigo.py

se crea el archivo perfectamente pero al ejecutarlo se abre y se cierra rapidamente por lo que le tengo que sacar caputa rapido y es eso lo que me aparece, al pareceer es un error de la libreria y la verdad es la primera vez que me pasa

Comment: Creo que tu app accede a un registro json, pero este no existe. Creo que de hay el problema. ¿Tu app sin compilar usa ese registro?

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Por favor no publiques código o mensajes de error/trazas de pila en imágenes, publica directamente el texto del código, el texto de los errores y los _stack traces_. Esto hace que sea menos complicado, para quien quiera ayudarte, investigar sobre el tema y hacer sus propias pruebas/adaptaciones al código, al escribir una respuesta y de esa forma aumenta tus posibilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Un saludo.

Comment: en el programa no uso ningun archivo json, el archivo json es propio de la libreria, ella misma se supone que la trae pero bueno no la encuentra